# Cumulative subtraction across rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table 1:
[image: table1:]

Table 2:
[image]

How can I subtract the Committed value (7) from the IncomingQuantity cumulatively across rows? So that the result would look like:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: what is the version of `SQL Server` you are using ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU2-GDR) (KB4458621) - 13.0.5201.2 (X64)   Aug 18 2018 07:38:15   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 2):

You need a cumulative sum and some arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when running_iq - incomingquantity >= committed then 0
             when running_iq > committed then running_iq - committed
             else incomingquantity
        end) as from_this_row
from (select t2.*, t1.committed,
             sum(incomingquantity) over (order by rowid) as running_iq
      from table1 t1 cross join
           table2 t2
     ) t;
```

Comment: Interesting. But it doesn't seem to quite work for me. The result I get:

I can't get it to format properly in comments... but it shows 0 for first row, 2 for second row... correct... but then starting 3rd row is is all 0s

Comment: @MrB . . . That is just the `else` part.  You want how much is remaining, not how much is used, so it should be the original value.

Answer (score 1):

you can also make use of the built-in functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()`, `LAST_VALUE()`, and `LAG()` with `CASE`

here is an example :

```
DECLARE 
    @t1 TABLE ( ProductID VARCHAR(50), ICommitted INT)

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES ('Some product', 7)

DECLARE 
    @t2 TABLE (RowID INT, DueDate DATE, IncommingQuantity INT)

INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES 
(1,'2018-11-19', 5),
(2,'2018-11-20', 4),
(3,'2018-11-20', 4),
(4,'2018-11-20', 3),
(5,'2018-11-22', 12)

SELECT  
    RowID 
,   DueDate
,   CASE 
        WHEN RowID = 1 
        THEN 0 
        WHEN RowID = LAST_VALUE(RowID) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) )    
        THEN IncommingQuantity
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DueDate ORDER BY RowID) > 1 
        THEN IncommingQuantity
        ELSE ICommitted - LAG(IncommingQuantity) OVER (ORDER BY RowID)
    END  IncommingQuantity
FROM @t2 t2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t1.ICommitted FROM @t1 t1) e
```

Comment: really nice! I have not used LAG or LAST_VALUE before. These are great for improving readability and reducing complexity

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this simply with WHILE loop inside a user function. The other solutions I would not work properly in 100% of cases